# I am trying to callout HTTP request(API) from Einstein chatbot. Is this possible/Can this be done?

Tags: bots

```
Http http = new Http();                   
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();              
request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');          
request.setMethod('GET');              
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);                
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {   
    Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)   
    JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());    
    List<Object> animals = (List<Object>) results.get('animals');   
    System.debug('Received the following animals:');    
    for (Object animal: animals) {   
        System.debug(animal);   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. Bots can call [Invocable Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) which can make callouts and return information. For this you would do the following:

1. Create a class with an invocable method that will run your callout
2. Update the `sfdc.chatbot.service.permset` permission set to include access to the class that contains the method you want to call
3. Add a remote site setting for the endpoint you are calling out to
4. Add a new action to your bot and choose the 'Apex' type. Select the invocable method you created.

Here's an example class that uses your callout and returns the text response back to the bot:

```
public class BotAction {

@InvocableMethod(Label ='Do Callout' description='does a callout')
public static List<String> DoCallout(){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        return new List<String> {response.getBody()};

    }
    return new List<String> {'Test'};
}
}
```

Comment: can u plz check my new question?

Comment: In your answer "response.getBody()" returns raw JSON like this - {"animals":["majestic badger","fluffy bunny","scary bear","chicken"]}. But I want to handle this response & show it properly to users in Bot, which i am not able to! Can u help?